# Asynctask not updating TextView in Fragment (Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

Currently, I am working on a project, where I have to use an Asynctask on multiple fragments. To start with, have I segregated the Asynctask from a Fragment java class, and I have created a new public Java class, where i've put the Asynctask. So far, everything works except the last part (and most important part), where the Asynctask needs to update the textviews on the fragment view.

This is the fragment Java class:

```
public class DataTabelFragment extends Fragment {

public TextView sensor1;

jsonAsynctask jsonasynctask = new jsonAsynctask(this);


public DataTabelFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_data_tabel, container, false );

    sensor1 = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.sensor1Box );

    new jsonAsynctask(this).execute();

    System.out.println("HEJ MED DIG");

    return view;

}

public void inExecute() {

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonasynctask.allId.size(); i++) {

       sensor1.append( jsonasynctask.allId.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allDevice.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allTemp.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allHum.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allBat.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allMode.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allLux.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allDate_time.get( i ) + "\n\n" );

    }

    }

}
```

This is the Java Class where in the Asynctask is:

```
public class jsonAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

DataTabelFragment dataTabelFragment;

JSONObject idArray, deviceArray, tempArray, humArray, batArray, modeArray, date_timeArray, luxArray;
JSONArray json2;

String basicAuth, line, json_string, json, cxwebURL, credentials, password, username;

String data = "";
String id = "";

List<String> allId = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allDevice = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allHum = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allBat = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allMode = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allDate_time = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allLux = new ArrayList<String>();

Gson gson;

ProgressDialog pd;

//HttpsURLConnection connection;
HttpURLConnection connection;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;

URL url;


public jsonAsynctask(DataTabelFragment dataTabelFragment) {
    this.dataTabelFragment = dataTabelFragment;
}

public void inBackground() {

    username = "xxx";
    password = "xxx";

    credentials = username + ":" + password;

    cxwebURL = "https://" + credentials + "@xxx.com/fetch.php?";

    try {

        url = new URL( cxwebURL );

        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        basicAuth = "Basic " + new String( encodeBase64URLSafeString( credentials.getBytes() ) );

        connection.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", basicAuth );
        connection.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Language", "en-US" );
        connection.setUseCaches( false );
        connection.setDoInput( true );
        connection.setDoOutput( true );
        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( stream ) );

        line = "";

        while (line != null) {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }

        System.out.println( "PRINT DATA HER:  " + data );

        json2 = new JSONArray( data );

        System.out.println( "DET HER ER json2" + json2 );

        for (int i = 0; i < json2.length(); i++) {
            idArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
            deviceArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
            tempArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
            humArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
            batArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
            modeArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
            date_timeArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
            luxArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
            id = idArray.getString( "id" );

            String temp = tempArray.getString( "temp" );
            String device = deviceArray.getString( "device" );
            String hum = humArray.getString( "hum" );
            String bat = batArray.getString( "bat" );
            String mode = modeArray.getString( "mode" );
            String date_time = date_timeArray.getString( "time" );
            String lux = luxArray.getString( "light" );

            allId.add( id );
            allDevice.add( device );
            allTemp.add( temp );
            allHum.add( hum );
            allBat.add( bat );
            allMode.add( mode );
            allDate_time.add( date_time );
            allLux.add( lux );

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static String encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[] binaryData) {

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString( binaryData, android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE );

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    inBackground();

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    //pd = new ProgressDialog( new MainActivity() );
    //pd.setMessage( "Være sød at vente" );
    //pd.setCancelable( false );
    //pd.show();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute( result );
        /*
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }*/

    gson = new Gson();

    json = gson.toJson( data );

    json_string = data;

     dataTabelFragment.inExecute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your ArrayLists actually contain data?

Comment: Yes, i've had system out prints showing me data in them. Also thanks for your time!

Comment: Try using `getActivity().runOnUiThread()` in your `inExecute()` method.

Comment: This is what it says, when i use it in my inExecute() method. required: runnable. found: no arguments

Comment: Yes you have to put a Runnable in too. Look up how to do that.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I'll look it up ASAP. Thanks for your help!

Comment: can u recheck that allId has data and you are printing log with same variable in fragment in the loop you are appending it to textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a bad usage of asynctask in your example. In addition, don't hold your data in your asynctask class to retrieve from a fragment. Instead, you should pass your data from onPostExecute method of asynctask to the fragment. The best way is to use an asynctask would be use it with an interface and pass data via that interface. I will put an example, i hope it helps.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements YourAsyncTask.YourInterface {


    public YourFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your, container, false);



        //do your initial things
        .
        .
        .

        YourAsyncTask yourAsyncTask = new YourAsyncTask(this);
        yourAsyncTask.execute();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onJobFinishListener(YourDataType yourData) {
        //when this method is trigered by your asynctask 
        //it means that you are in ui thread and update your ui component

        //TODO: update ui component with your data
    }
}
```

and below is an asynctask example witn an interface parameter:

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

    private YourInterface yourInterfaceListener;

    private YourDataType yourData; //this data should be calculated in doInBackground method and send via interface

    public YourAsyncTask(YourInterface yourInterfaceListener) {
        this.yourInterfaceListener = yourInterfaceListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        //do your all background tasks here
        .
        .
        .
        yourData = do something here to fill your data..

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        yourInterfaceListener.onJobFinishListener(yourData);
    }

    public interface YourInterface{
        void onJobFinishListener(YourDataType yourData);
    }
}
```

Edit: I didn't see above answer when i was writing this. It s also a nice example

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please elaborate, YourDataType and yourData, i'm not sure what i'm supposed to do here. I am sorry, but i'm new at Android.

Comment: in your example YourDataType yourData will be List<String> allId

Answer (score 0):

Better make use of Interface.

I have also used in one of my project for almost same scenario.

1) Create Interface

```
 public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }
```

2) Initialise interface in constructor of Async task class like you doing

```
public jsonAsynctask(AsyncResponse asynctaskResponse) {
    this.asynctaskResponse = asynctaskResponse;
}
```

3) Implement interface in your fragment

```
new jsonAsynctask(new jsonAsynctask.AsyncResponse() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void processFinish(String output) {
                                       //  do whatever you want do here                                          
                                    }
                                }).execute(videouri.toString(), f.getPath());
```

Hope It will help.

Answer (score 0):

The interface approach solution example by parliament is the best approach. I would also suggest to use a WeakReference on the private YourInterface yourInterfaceListener;

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

private WeakReference<YourInterface> yourInterfaceListener;

private YourDataType yourData; //this data should be calculated in doInBackground method and send via interface

public YourAsyncTask(YourInterface yourInterfaceListener) {
    this.yourInterfaceListener = new WeakReference<YourInterface>(yourInterfaceListener);
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    //do your all background tasks here
    .
    .
    .
    yourData = do something here to fill your data..

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    super.onPostExecute(o);
    if(yourInterfaceListener.get()!=null){
        yourInterfaceListener.get().onJobFinishListener(yourData);
    }
}

public interface YourInterface{
    void onJobFinishListener(YourDataType yourData);
}
}
```